# python client for SOAP-based RPC style web service

Tags: java, python, web-services, soap

I have a simple SOAP-based RPC style web service written in java.It has simple string method which is take string value from  client and display.Client also written in java.But how can I write a python client to do the same thing?Thanks.

Used codes are given bellow.

Service endpoint

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.webservice.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

@Override
public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
    return "Hello World JAX-WS " + name;
}

}
```

Java Web Service Client

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import com.test.webservice.HelloWorld;

public class HelloWorldClient{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl");

    //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
//2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
    QName qname = new QName("http://webservice.test.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");

    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

    HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);

    System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("name"));

}

}

}
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I've tried this tutorial   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238778/Web-Services-in-Ruby-Python-and-Java  but it gave me this error:  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SOAPpy\WSDL.py", line 114, in __getattr__
AttributeError: fetchData

Comment: previous URL should be http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/webservices/tutorials/06_programming/python/soap/soappy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
import suds

class Client:
def __init__(self):
    self.client = suds.client.Client("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl")

def getHelloWorldAsString(self):
    return self.client.service.getHelloWorldAsString("name")

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
client = Client()
result = client.getHelloWorldAsString()
print result
```

Source:-http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238778/Web-Services-in-Ruby-Python-and-Java